# How to get thread IDs from a memory dump in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to create a script that runs thread specific commands to output information for each thread into a separate file. Is there a way to get thread ID that I can run in the command similar to this: `~${threadId} e!clrstack`.
Ultimately here is what I'm shooting for:

```
.foreach(tid {!threads})
{
  .logopen c:\temp\${tid}.txt;
  ~${tid}e !dumpstack;
  ~${tid}e !clrstack;
  ~${tid}e !dso;
  ~${tid}e kb 200;
  .logclose
}
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
.foreach /pS 1 /pS2 /pS3 /pS4 /pS5 /ps 3 (l {!runaway})
{
  .printf "${l}\n";
}
```

The issue with this that it has the value I'm looking for with OSID. Looks like this `<wantedID>:<OSID>`.
How can I separate the part I need or is there an easier way to get thread ID from a memory dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about the use of `.foreach` together with `~e`, because that's somehow duplicate (just the fact that you're limiting `~e` to one thread doesn't result in a nested loop).

Is the command

```
~*e .logopen /t d:\debug\log.txt; !dumpstack; !clrstack; !dso; kb 200; .logclose
```

sufficient for you? The log file name will not have the thread ID.

Regarding your skip tokens of `.foreach`, I think you can only use `/pS` and `/ps` once. Your statement is equivalent to

```
.foreach /pS 5 /ps 3 (l {!runaway}) { ... }
```

**If the thread ID really matters**

It seems that the OS thread IDs are really important.

As using `.foreach` directly on any command like `!threads`, `~` or `!runaway` seems not flexible and reliable enough, I propose to use `.shell find` to get at least some consistency in output.

I'll use `!teb` to get the thread ID, because it is separated by a space and therefore the output of `.shell find` can be used as input for `.foreach`.

The complete command I come up with:

```
~*e .foreach /pS 3 /ps 20 (tid {.shell -ci "!teb" find "ClientId"}) { .logopen d:\debug\logs\log${tid}.txt; !dumpstack; !clrstack; !dso; kb 200; .logclose}
```

**Using pykd as an extension**

Using [PyKd - Python extension for WinDbg](https://pykd.codeplex.com/), the result can be achieved like this:

Create a file *tid.py*, put it next to the pykd.pyd extension and give it the following content:

```
from pykd import *
threads = getProcessThreads()
for t in threads:
    print(hex(ptrPtr(t+0x24))[2:-1])
```

`getProcessThreads()` gives you the addresses of the TEBs. At offset 0x24 you can find the thread ID. `ptrPtr()` reads a memory address, `hex()` is self-explaining, `[2:` removes the 0x head and `:-1]` removes the trailing L (don't ask me why it has a trailing L).

In WinDbg

```
.load pykd.pyd
!py tid.py; *** Gives one thread ID per line, nice for .foreach
.foreach (tid {!py tid.py}) { .logopen d:\debug\logs\log_${tid}.txt; ~~[${tid}]s; !dumpstack; !clrstack; !dso; kb 200; .logclose}
```

Comment: I can use ~*e to loop through all threads, but my primary goal is to get thread ID that I can use for a file name. I can use @$tid variable to get thread ID but it gives me OSID rather than decimal ID # specific for the process.
Thanks for correcting my /pS usage!

Comment: @iSharemore: updated my answer, not using an extension like pykd yet. I'm looking into pykd to get the same result.

Comment: @iSharemore: I added another solution using pykd

Comment: that works thanks for this solution.
Want to mention another option here PowerDBG (http://piers7.blogspot.com/2010/04/automating-windbg-with-powershell.html). Similar to what you suggested but using PowerShell.